# put some values in a for loop in an array

Tags: java

I am filtering a file rows with an if condition and I need to make a new array which containing only the values that satisfy the condition.

I can get them in the console but I don't know how to assign them to a table, can anyone help me please?

```
String section_title;
for (int j=11; j<row_num; j++) 
{
    Row row = (Row) rowIterator.next();
    Cell s0 = sheet.getRow(j-1).getCell(0);
    if(s0.toString()!="" )
    {
        section_title = s0.toString();
        d  = j-1;    
        System.out.println(d);
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to stack overflow.  I cleaned up your code formatting a little.  Please take the time to elaborate on your question more or it will get closed (not up to standards).  What are row and cell?  Show us your imports please.  Also, what are you working in?  An excel API, making a web user interface project, or something else?  Or by table do you just mean another array or list (as opposed to a literal table)?  Thanks! and welcome to SO!

Comment: Are you using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) to read an [Excel](https://products.office.com/en/excel) file?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an [arraylist](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp) object to hold those values.

It would look something like this:

```
String section_title;
ArrayList<int> list = new ArrayList<int>();  // instanciate the array list
for (int j=11; j<row_num; j++) 
{
    Row row = (Row) rowIterator.next();
    Cell s0 = sheet.getRow(j-1).getCell(0);
    if(s0.toString()!="" )
    {
        section_title = s0.toString();
        d  = j-1;    
        list.add(d);  // Add d to the list
     }
}

System.out.println(list);  // Print the final list
```

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to scan some input and to get an array of int as a result.
As we do not know the final number of entries for the array, we should use something with a variable length for that purpose. Usually, this would be a List of some kind, but List is not defined for int (or other primitives), only for object types like Integer. So we would need a transformation step after collecting the numbers.

Since Java 8, we have Streams, and with that, the problem can be solved more directly:

```
String section_title;
var builder = IntStream.builder();
for( var j = 11; j < row_num; ++j ) 
{
    var row = (Row) rowIterator.next();
    Cell s0 = sheet.getRow( j - 1 ).getCell( 0 );
    if( !s0.toString().isEmpty() )
    {
        section_title = s0.toString();
        builder.add( Integer.valueOf( j - 1 ) );
     }
}

var array = builder.build().toArray();

System.out.println( array );
```

Under the hood, this solution may end up to be nearly the same as one using Collections. But it still looks neater.